# nginx rewrite url without changing browser address

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, rewrite, url

I want to change the url of a request but the browser address should not change. 
To achieve this I have tried the below configuration:

```
location /my-website {          

    proxy_pass  http://tomcat/my-website;
}

location =/my-website { 

        rewrite /my-website$(.*) $1/my-website/mypage/index.html last;

}
```

Although doing this the request does get the correct address but the address bar of the browser also changes.

Also tried;

```
location /my-website {                  
    proxy_pass  http://tomcat;
    rewrite /my-website$(.*) $1/my-website/page/index.html break;

}
```

Any suggestion(s) on improving this configuration?

**Expected Output**

> **address bar:** protocol://localhost/my-website
>
> **actual:** protocol://localhost/my-website/page

**Current Output**

> **address bar:** protocol://localhost/my-website/page
>
> **actual:** protocol://localhost/my-website/page

Things tried :

- https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/436/nginx-rewrite-url-examples-with-without-redirect-address#.W3_a6M4zaUk
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322826/nginx-rewrite-without-change-url

**Edit**

The above issue is being faced on a 302 redirect. For other cases the url is changed without changing the browser address. I am handling the latter case using the below config:

```
location /my-website {      

        proxy_pass  http://tomcat;
        rewrite ^(.*)my-website/src(.*)$ $1my-website/page/src$2 break;


    }
```

i.e. that location is followed by /src and it works.

In the 302 case the location is just my-website/ and the above tried things fail.

**My file config:**

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;



    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"' 
                      '"$upstream_http_location"';    

    rewrite_log  on;

    #log_format  graylog2_format  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" <msec=$msec|connection=$connection|connection_requests=$connection_requests|millis=$request_time>';

    error_log logs/error.log warn;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    map $http_user_agent $ua_redirect {
    default 'abc';        
    }



    upstream docker-mysite {
        server localhost:9012;
    }


    proxy_set_header     Host $host;
    proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header     X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout   900;

    client_max_body_size 0; 

server {
    listen       80;      


    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main; 

    #below config works
    location /mysite {                      
        proxy_pass  http://docker-mysite;
        rewrite ^(.*)mysite/src(.*)$ $1mysite/$ua_redirect/src$2 break;

    }
    #below config works but modifies the browser url hence the issue
    location = /mysite {    
        proxy_pass  http://docker-mysite;               
        rewrite /mysite(.*)$ /mysite/$ua_redirect$1 break;

    }

}

}
```

**Logs**

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2018:11:46:07 +0500] "GET /mysite/login?code=token HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "http://localhost/loginapp/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-"http://localhost/mysite/abc
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2018:11:46:07 +0500] "GET /mysite/abc HTTP/1.1" 404 0 "http://localhost/loginapp/web/index.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36" "-"-
```

Comment: i'm testing with the configuration similar to yours and it work well for me can you add variable $upstream_http_location in nginx access log and share it in here? and maybe give us full config?

Comment: @IlhamSulaksono sure i will upload it

Answer (score 2):

Your rewrite logic is fine since its working correctly in normal schenerio. Browser URL is changing for 302 redirect because `rewrite` directive just changes the request URI, not the response of request.

A typical 302 reponse looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://overrideurlrewriting.com
```

`Location` header in 302 response forces the browser to follow mentioned url.

Possible solution is to modify `Location` header from the proxied response (in case of 302 redirect) using `proxy_redirect` directive

**Helpful links:**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025618/2073920

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location /my-website {                  
    proxy_pass  http://tomcat;
    rewrite /my-website(.*)$ $1/my-website/page/index.html break;
}
```

I think you have a `$` out of place in your regexp - it should be at the end of the regexp. I can't tell exactly what your intentions are but you might also want to change your rewrite target, so that pages other than `index.html` will work:

```
location /my-website {
    proxy_pass  http://tomcat:8000;
    rewrite /my-website(.*)$ /my-website/page$1 break;
}
```

Comment: To extend on this answer: Your rewrite of `rewrite /my-website$(.*)` is basically saying that the URL ends at `/my-website` as $ is the symbol for end-of-line in PCRE. Nginx uses the PCRE library during compilation. A good place to test out your regex is at https://regex101.com/

Comment: just tried your solution. the url is correctly re written however the browser address is also changed. i don't know if it will help but the re write is to happen on a 302 server redirect. For other cases the following config works fine                                                                                                    proxy_pass http://docker-iam;                                                    rewrite ^(.*)iam/src(.*)$ $1iam/$ua_redirect/src$2 break;

Comment: i will add this to the question as well